# calculate discrete S transform for given discrete time series

Tags: matlab, loops, fft, wavelet

let us consider following  Page :

http://djj.ee.ntu.edu.tw/S_Transform.pdf

paragraph  2.3 The Discrete S Transform

let say that we have  sampled version of signal  x, and given sampling frequency fs,i have calculated discrete Fourier transform using following code

```
function y=DFT(x);
N=length(x);
D=zeros(N,N);
for k=1:N
    for n=1: N
        D(k,n)=exp((-j*(k-1)*2*pi*(n-1))/N);
    end
end
y=D*x'/N;
end
```

and started to estimate  discrete  S transform

```
function [S]=discrete_s_transform(x,fs);
%compute discrete  s transform
%fs-sampling frequency 
N=length(x); % length of signal
T=1/fs; % sampling period
Y=DFT(X);
```

how can i continue  related to this part ?
[image]

clearly loops are not problem to implement,just they go  from 1 to N instead of 0 to N-1 because of matlab vectors are 1 based,but what about main code?multiplication to exponential? coudl you please help me to  finish S transform ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sum depends only on *m* so I assume that other parameters as well as function `H((m+n)/(NT))` are defined. Via for-loops the simplest one is:

```
function [S]=discrete_s_transform(x);
N=length(x); % length of signal
S=0;
m=0;
for i=1:N
S=S+H((m+n)/(NT))*exp(a)*exp(b*m/N);
m=m+1; 
end
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: but  S  should be  two dimensional matrix is not it?

Comment: You can loop over 'jT' and 'n/(NT)' to get 2-D representation where each element of it should be summed over 'm' but in general S not necessary to be a 2-D array according to 2.14

Comment: create two arrays b=1:n/(NT) and other is a=complex(1:T). Also it seems that they have a couple of typos in there.

Comment: The write up better to check for S-function but code I have provided is general for finding sums for N=0...N-1. You can add above two for-loops of size 'a' and 'b' to get a 2-D array.